# Calling methods from different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods, locking

I have 4 windows forms and they use one method of one another form. This method must be processed just by one of the forms. If a thread wants to use this method, it must be sure that method is not called at this time by other threads.

I have a solution like that

```
bool methodIsBusy = false;

void Method()
{
     methodIsBusy = true;

     //do method things

     //done method things

     methodIsBusy = false;

}
```

and use **methodIsBusy** to know that method is occupied by a thread or not. Are any more creative solutions to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: If you're calling methods of forms from threads other than the UI thread, it's almost guaranteed that you're doing something wrong. This won't end well. Rethink what you're doing.

Comment: Why? I am creating 4 forms from a main form, by instatiating. Why can not I use main threads methods in new forms? What can cause a problem?

Comment: @MehmetErkol The problem is not calling the methods of another form, it's calling them *from a non-UI thread*.  You should only ever be calling such a method *from the UI thread*, and at that point since all of the calls are in the UI thread, you already know that they're not running at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest traditional pattern would be more like this, using [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement). Code inside of a lock (referred to as a [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section)) can only be executed by one thread at a time.

```
object lockObject = new object();  //Can be anything, an object will do

void Method()
{
     lock (lockObject)
     {

         //do method things

         //done method things

     }    
}
```

You could in theory use a `bool` but you'd have to write busywait code, like this:

```
//Don't do this!
while (methodIsBusy)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10); //or some number
}
```

This kind of code will end up using more resources than a lock, which is designed for exactly this purpose.

Comment: In your lock example when 1. Thread is executing, and an order for tread2 is ready to be executed, what is happening? Is 2nd thread wait for 1. Thread to finish his work then execute or never execute?

Comment: In the second thread. code will halt at the beginning of the `lock {` block until the first thread has exited the same block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) to ensure that only one thread can enter a critical block capsuled with a `lock` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Also have a look at [Monitor.TryEnter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.tryenter(v=vs.110).aspx) - which allows you to test if you can enter, not lock and go out w/o doing somth. Just make really sure to use a `try {} finalley { Monitor.Exit(obj); }` to release your lock obj again.